# Hysteresis phenomenon on a tungsten filament

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current

I have a lamp with a standard filament bulb. A dimmer allows to modulate its intensity. It's an old low-end dimmer, so I assume it's a potentiometer that regulates the current in the bulb.

When I vary the dimmer, I observe (qualitatively) the following intensity curve (note the hysteresis). Basically, the bulb doesn't light up until the dimmer is halfway turned.

[image: Observed IV-curve of light bulb]

What explains that the bulb does not light up initially, but that it can light up on the descending stage?

Comment: Known, common effect in a TRIAC dimmer. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/429658/questions-regarding-eliminating-hysteresis-in-ac-dimmer

Answer (score 1):

When reducing power you've already got an hot incandescent filament, but while powering up the filament is cold and has not yet reached it's incandescent (for visible light) temperature. In essence, it's the thermal mass vs rate of heat loss of the filament and light bulb that provides the apparent hysteresis. Try leaving the dimmer at half the "turn on" position for a long time. Does the light bulb eventually "extinguish"? Alternatively, leave the the dimmer at half the "turn on" position for a long time. Does the light bulb eventually light, even dimly. Does it heat?

BTW, even old dimmers are very rarely potentiometers, since these would dissipate enormous amounts of power, even for a single light bulb load. Yours is more likely a simple TRIAC-based circuit.